# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'did' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'did' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'MvcApplication1.Controllers.EmployeeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
i don't know from what this exception but i searched more but still not reach to solve this error can help me if you can .

```
  public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Depts { get; set; }
}


[Table("tblDepartment")]
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }     
    public List<Employee> employeees { get; set; }

}
  [Table("TblEmployees")]
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

}


public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext();

        var employ = emp.Employees.Where(empp => empp.DepartmentId == id).ToList();

         return View(employ);
    }





@using MvcApplication1.Models;

@model IEnumerable<Department>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "departments";
}

<div>
    <h2>departments</h2>
    <ul>
        @foreach (Department department in @Model)
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(department.Name,"Index", "Employee", new { id = department.ID }, null)</li>

        }

    </ul>
</div>

@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Employee>
@using MvcApplication1.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EmployeeList";
}
<div>
    <h2>EmployeeList</h2>
    <ul>
        @foreach (Employee emp in @Model)
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(emp.Name, "Details", new { id = emp.EmployeeId })</li>
        }

    </ul>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Department List", "Index", "Department")

</div>

 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");          

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = ""}
        );
    }
```

Comment: What's the URL being opened when you get that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = ""}
        );
```

The id parameter is not optional, so you are calling any action without a value for this parameter, you can define the id parameter to be optional:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```